# Whatsapp workaround?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, privacy

What I have:
- I don't want to install Whatsapp on my phone because I don't want it to access my personal data.
- There's an organisation that requires me to use Whatsapp to communicate with them.
- These two statements are mutually exclusive....

What I want:
- Is there any way for me to use Whatsapp without installing it on my phone? (I already have a Whatsapp user account.)
- Alternatively, is there a way to install and use Whatsapp without giving it access to all my data? (Contacts, calendar, camera, photos, etc etc.) I use Android 7.1.2 because there's no newer ROM for my phone.

I realize this might be offensive to some users ("use it or don't!") but please look past that. I'm trying to satisfy competing demands here.

**Update:**

- I had another go at this. Installed the app again, did *not* give contacts permissions (or any other), and the app starts okay (on iOS it flatly refuses to start, so at least this is better on Android).
- I cannot create a new message though. When I touch the "new message" button, I get a popup to share my contacts. *No!* This is not going to happen.
- It won't let me just type in a phone number and send to that user. (This is allowed in Signal, for instance.)

Comment: It is possible to block those details from being shared with Whatsapp using this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rikka.appops&hl=en_US), but I am uncertain whether Whatsapp would work. You can try and see for yourself.

Comment: @Firelord WhatsApp works if reading Contacts is denied using AppOps or XPrivacyLua.

Comment: Another way could be to run WhatsApp in another Work Profile / User Account using some app like Shelter. This way storage will also be isolated.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the permission given to WhatsApp from setting --> Apps and notification --> App info --> Whatsapp --> Permissions and then turn off the permissions which you don't want to share. Whatsapp needs a valid sim card to run which can be used on phone or desktop only. Hence, you can run Whatsapp on desktop having a sim card option.

Comment: Thanks - but if I don't grant the contacts permission then the app refuses to start. If I leave it on even just once, the contacts data is taken.

Comment: Hey, I just tried doing this thing and for me, the app still works. It does not show the name of the person but the app still works.